# How to make .service condition script under /etc/systemd which would stop/kill service when certain condition is fullfilled?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have service like below, but how to add condition which would stop/kill the service when certain condition is fullfilled, for ex /tmp/killsoc file exist?

```
[Unit]                                                                          
Description=Socat tunnel service                                                                 

[Service]                                                                       
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat tcp-l:31120,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:6443
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of these conditions, maybe `ConditionPathExists=`

> ConditionArchitecture=, ConditionVirtualization=, ConditionHost=,
>   ConditionKernelCommandLine=, ConditionSecurity=, ConditionCapability=,
>   ConditionACPower=, ConditionNeedsUpdate=, ConditionFirstBoot=,
>   ConditionPathExists=, ConditionPathExistsGlob=,
>   ConditionPathIsDirectory=, ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=,
>   ConditionPathIsMountPoint=, ConditionPathIsReadWrite=,
>   ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=, ConditionFileNotEmpty=,
>   ConditionFileIsExecutable=

more details here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: These conditions are only tested when the service is being started either by a dependency or by a manual `systemctl start`. I vaguely understand the op might want systemd to react to the the file being created/removed at runtime. Check out `.path` units for that purpose.